# Missing artifact org.apache.ignite:ignite-hibernate_5.1:jar:2.3.0

Tags: jhipster, ignite

I am trying to implement Hibernate 2nd level cache with Apache Ignite. For this, I used following maven dependency in pom.xml based on Apache Ignite [official documentation](https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/hibernate-l2-cache). I got following exception **Missing artifact org.apache.ignite:ignite-hibernate_5.1:jar:2.3.0** when I build the project. Code uploaded to [github](https://github.com/pavankjadda/ApacheIgnite-JHipster-Docker). I am using Apache Ignite 2.3.0 version. I tried other versions too and nothing worked

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
      <artifactId>ignite-hibernate_5.1</artifactId>
      <version>${ignite.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: There are no Ignite dependencies in the linked github project. Perhaps you need to push the latest updates there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ignite-hibernate` module is not deployed to Maven Central due to licensing restrictions. You can either build these artifacts from source on your own, or use 3rd party repos: https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#3rdparty

Comment: Thanks, Valebtin. This helped

Comment: I downloaded jar file from http://www.gridgainsystems.com/nexus/content/repositories/external/org/apache/ignite/ignite-hibernate_5.1/2.3.3/ and included in build path